# Working with mod.log in praw

Tags: python, praw

I'm working on a bot that will search the moderation log on reddit for removal actions, but am coming up short on documentation for the `subreddit().mod.log()` method.

As of right now, all I can retrieve from it is the moderator performing the action and the subreddit the action was in, neither of which are helpful for this project. I need to access the post ID as well as the author of the post for this project.

Right now, this is what I figured would work:

```
for i in r.subreddit(subbie).mod.log(action='removelink'):
    print i.author
```

however, I simply get the error: `AttributeError: 'ModAction' object has no attribute 'author'`

[The documentation](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/subredditmoderation.html#praw.models.reddit.subreddit.SubredditModeration.log) has not been very helpful in this case, either.

Answer (score 1):

run vars(item) to see available attributes of a ModAction object. The desired attribute in this case is: `target_author`. Hope it helps you and/or anyone else who might see this.